# jquery parents selector - multiple parents in that

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

Is this a valid syntax:

```
$("span").parents("li[data='UM'], li[data='Me']")
```

I want to traverse to parent of span and see if that parent is a li with value of data attribute as "UM" OR li with value of data attribute as "Me". 
Basically looking for OR operator in parents.

Comment: Did you test it? *(Hint: that's perfectly valid.)*

Comment: If you are looking for the closest parent matching the criteria `$("span").closest("li[data='UM'], li[data='Me']")` will do - yours also is corrent...

Comment: Yes, I think its working, tested for a scenario, but just wanted to double check.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ks38e/1/

Comment: There is no question in this post

Comment: Arun: looking at the fiddle, it seems it works fine..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.closest()` instead:

```
 $("span").closest("li[data='UM'], li[data='Me']")
```

Comment: Well, what exactly would be the difference in case parents is used?

Comment: @whyAto8:how are you trying to target these parents.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar - Well, its just the same as I wrote, i need to access the parents...and then perform some action...

Comment: Hello from the future... `closest()` stops looking once it finds something to return, and returns one jQuery object. `parents()` keeps looking all the way up the DOM tree until it runs out of elements, and returns a collection of jQuery objects.

Answer (score 2):

Yes using  closest() is definitely the right procedure.

```
$("span").closest("li[data='UM'], li[data='Me']");
```

http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($("span").closest("li").filter("li[data='UM'], li[data='Me']").length) { // there is... }
```

Comment: Review: Some explanation of what you've fixed would be appreciated. -1 until you fix this.

Comment: i didnt fix anything, i just added a condition. wayne till you read this

Comment: still I insist that you should write some description to the code you posted.